# How to get list content from json without jsx in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I've been looking to achieve this but I didn't found much information about how to do this without JSX. Cause JSX it's not an option for me, I only can use react by adding tags in the html file and I don't like the idea of using babel for a production app.

I found out the way to get the content of any key except roles list. I would like to be able to get the information of each role. Is this possible?

This is my json response:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userId": 1,
        "fullName": "xxxxx",
        "ldapId": "xxxx",
        "contraseña": "xxxxxx!",
        "email": "c@mail",
        "deleteFlag": "N ",
        "access": "Y ",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": 2,
                "roleName": "Admin",
                "focusAccount": "N ",
                "channelAccount": "N ",
                "menuHome": null
            },
            {
                "roleId": 1,
                "roleName": "Dashboard",
                "focusAccount": "N ",
                "channelAccount": "N ",
                "menuHome": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Reactjs code:

```
class User extends React.Component {

  state = {
    user: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard?user=' + 'xxxxx')
      .then(res => {
       const user = res.data
       this.setState({user});
      })
  }


  render () {
         const {user} = this.state


         console.log({user})
         return React.createElement("ul", null, Object.keys(user).map( data => (
             React.createElement("li", null, user[data].fullName)

         )))


     }
}



ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(User, {}, null), document.getElementById('root') );
```

Comment: Can you use Axios or any other ajax library?

Comment: `user[data].fullName`  if your just after fullName, then `user.fullName`, `Object.keys` isn't required here.

Comment: @Jerodev I'm using axios, could try with another library but, does it make any difference?

Comment: @keith I don't understand what you expose. If I do this  `React.createElement("li", null, user.fullName)` it doesn't  work.

Comment: Unrelated, but "I don't like the idea of using babel for a production app"?! Why not? This is going to make your JS/React experience more verbose, difficult, and error-prone than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code ->

```
return React.createElement("ul", null, Object.keys(user).map( data => (
   React.createElement("li", null, user[data].fullName)
)))
```

Does not really make much sense, you loop all the keys of `user`, and then asking for `fullName`,  if you wanted to get all entries and place in an `<li>` then it would maybe make more sense.

But if your after more fine grained control, then ->

```
return React.createElement("ul", null, [
   React.createElement("li", null, user.fullName),
   React.createElement("li", null, user.email)
])
```

If your after rendering the `user` object totally automatic, then that's also possible too, but there would be a bit more to do as you have `object's within object's`, so then you maybe want an `<UL>` inside your `<LI>`'s.

Below is an example, instead of using `axios` to get your data, I've just used a const, but it will work fine with `axios` too.  I've also done a pretend `async` requests using a `setTimeout`, and a simple `loading..` indicator.

```js
const userrec = {
  "user": {
    "userId": 1,
        "fullName": "xxxxx",
        "ldapId": "xxxx",
        "contraseña": "xxxxxx!",
        "email": "c@mail",
        "deleteFlag": "N ",
        "access": "Y ",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": 2,
                "roleName": "Admin",
                "focusAccount": "N ",
                "channelAccount": "N ",
                "menuHome": null
            },
            {
                "roleId": 1,
                "roleName": "Dashboard",
                "focusAccount": "N ",
                "channelAccount": "N ",
                "menuHome": null
            }
        ]
    }
};


class User extends React.Component {

  state = {
    user: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //lets pretend it's async
    setTimeout(() => 
      this.setState({user: userrec.user}), 1000);
  }

  render () {
    const {user} = this.state
    if (user.fullName === undefined) 
      return React.createElement("div", null, 'loading..'); 
    
    return React.createElement("ul", null, [
      React.createElement("li", null, user.fullName),
      React.createElement("li", null, user.email)
    ]);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(User), document.getElementById("mount"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="mount"/>
```

Comment: Thanks by the explanation, but now I'm in a worst situation than before. I changed the code exactly by yours and now I can only see the dots of each `<li>`, no content at all.

Comment: @CarolinaPonce  I've created you a snippet to show you it working.

Comment: @CarolinaPonce  If your just getting `dots`, then `user` doesn't contain what you think it does, it's maybe `user.user.fullName`, as the first `user` is just your javascript reference to `user` object returned from `axios`..

Comment: thank you sou much  with this answer, It helped me to have an optimized code. I tried then, with your answer to find a way to show the content of the roles list (the one inside the json) but I still don't know how, even with this new way. Could you enlight me one more time?

Comment: @CarolinaPonce In your code -> `const user = res.data`, could you add -> `console.log(user); console.log(typeof user);`  If it's say `{user: {...` and `object`, then you need -> `const user = res.data.user`, if you get `string` for the typeof, you will need to `JSON.parse` first..